# Type error for a column that exists within the dataframe I am trying to call

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, keyerror

Essentially, I am getting a key error in my jupyter notebook when trying to merge two data frames. As I understand it, a key error will only occur if said column I am trying to merge on doesn't exist. The column I am trying to merge on most certainly exists and I am confident that it is spelled correctly. For more context, I am merging my 'region' data frame onto my main 'sales' data frame on 'region_id' (the column associated with the key error).

```
sales = sales.merge(region,on='region_id')
sales.head()
```

sales csv was imported as

```
sales=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/tjwav/OneDrive/Desktop/data/sales.csv')
```

region csv was imported as

```
region=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/tjwav/OneDrive/Desktop/data/region.csv')
```

Sales table

```
        product_id  time_id  customer_id  store_id  store_sales  store_cost  
0              337      371         6280         2         1.50      0.5100   
1             1512      371         6280         2         1.62      0.6318   
2              963      371         4018         2         2.40      0.7200   
3              181      371         4018         2         2.79      1.0323   
4             1383      371         4018         2         5.18      2.1756
```

Comment: I am relatively new to stack overflow so i could not get multiple pictures in but I have two more to verify my spelling. print(region.columns.tolist()) and region.get('region_id', default = 'no_region'). both of which verify that I am spelling the column name correctly [region_id]

Comment: show your data as text/code in your question, not as pictures. also show the exact error please.

Comment: The exact error is KeyError: 'region_id'. I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by show my data as text/code.

Comment: with that i mean show us the data of the two csv files, you can just copy paste them in here. right now we can't do anything.

Comment: for example, print `sales.head(5)` and `region.head(5)` after importing them and the data that gets printed you copy to your question

Comment: Appreciate you being patient with me! I have the data but my question is more or less how I would I get it into my post? Can I copy the data straight from the image on jupyter?

Comment: yes, just copy the output and paste it here. here in your question select the data and press `crtl+K`

Comment: This has been pretty painstaking for me I apologize. decided to copy the print statement from the output as I could not format it by trying to copy the table. Is what I've posted above an example of what you would need to see?

Comment: everybody has been there. have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want. lots of things are explained there how to get helped the best way on SO. To your question. Where is your column `region_id` ? It is just not there, that's why you get a keyError

Comment: Please include a sample of ‘region.csv’ as well so that SO users can replicate your issue.